# Remap command key in mac only for emacs

Tags: macos, emacs

So, this is default my setup now: Mac OSX + Aquamacs

```
C-X=control+x
M-X=option/alt+x
```

So, my command is basically unused in emacs. So, I need to remap control to command (UPDATE: and vice versa) ONLY for emacs, but not for other Mac application.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So you want the command key to function as a control key in Emacs? Add this to your `~/.emacs` file:

```
(setq mac-command-modifier 'control)
```

Comment: Awesome that worked like a charm! But, I wanted to swap the functionality, i.e. for emacs, put the functionality of command to control and vice-versa. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: zengr: sure, `(setq mac-control-modifier 'meta)`

Comment: Done, awesome!!